# Defining success_url with kwargs

Tags: python, django

How would one go about providing `success_url` in a class-based view with `kwargs`? Right now I'm overriding `get_success_url` and calling `reverse` with the `kwargs` from there. Is that best practice or is there a better way of doing it?

Current method:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('url_name', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

Is there a way to do this with the `success_url` attribute?

Comment: That's fine, that's why they added the method. You can also look at reverse_lazy.

Comment: @Johan, yeah I first actually tried `success_url = reverse_lazy('url_name', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']})` which for me seems better (attribute rather than function override). The trouble is that I don't have access to `self` here so my limited knowledge has me thinking that there's no choice but to override `get_success_url`.

Comment: There's no problem overriding it in the function. One other thing you can look at is get_absolute_url. You define that in the model and then you don't need to define the success_url in your view

Comment: @Johan, yeah I also read up on `get_absolute_url`. The thing is I'm not using a `ModelForm` so it's not applicable in my situation, right? Thanks for all the suggestions, by the way.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. Take a look at this site - great resource for CBV http://ccbv.co.uk/